# Categories and Subcategories - How to Design Database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, select

So I am creating a database that has a Category, sub categories, sub sub categories, sub sub sub categories... you get the point, it  can go on forever.

So I made a table.
Category
Name|ParentID|ID|Budget|

For the sake of explaining my situation, I will pretend each category has a budget.
How would I make a Select statement that is able to get the total budget for a category and its sub categories and their sub categories. This also means that when I enter into a sub category I should also be able to see the total budget of its own sub categories.

Any advice will help me greatly!

Thanks guys!

Edit: I forgot to mention, the database is MySQL. I will be displaying the data on a webpage using PHP.

Comment: @JohnSmith - question not clear. please tell what actually you want to store in database

Comment: `Category Name|ParentID|ID|Budget|` is bad design. Where is category Id here ?

Comment: well SQL Server and Oracle gives u the flexibility of CTE .. mysql does not support the "with" clause. so the best way in such a scenario would be to find ways of traversing the trees. http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html .. http://iqwen.net/question/345840 .. u might want to read thru those links.. in the 2nd link u might want to read the answer by andriy M which details u what u cud n cud not do with mysql..

Answer (score 0):

You are using a difficult model for searching (Adjacency List Model).  Have you thought about incorporating the Nested Set Model?  Here's a good article on the topic:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

In regards to your question, a recursive function will be your best bet.  I don't think you can do this with SQL alone unless you know the potential universe of sub types.  In which case, you could join the tables multiple times -- something like this:

```
SELECT t.CatName, SUM(t.Budget+t2.Budget+t3.Budget...)
FROM YourTable t
    LEFT JOIN YourTable t2 ON t2.parentid = t1.id
    LEFT JOIN YourTable t3 ON t3.parentid = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN YourTable t4 ON t4.parentid = t3.id
    ...
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following links will take you to the right path..

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

http://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?30908-Recursive-MYSQL-Query